# Keep first div in jquery accordion open

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm looking for a way to modify the following to allow to first div to be open on load.
Is it an easy fix? Would really appreciate the help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".expand-menu .menu_header").click(function() {
  if($(this).next("div").is(":visible")){
    $(this).next("div").slideDown("slow");
  } else {
    $(".expand-menu .category_list").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
  }
});
```

Comment: Try to use jQuery accordion plugin. Maybe it will be better?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually fire the click handler for the first tab

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expand-menu .menu_header").click(function() {
        if($(this).next("div").is(":visible")){
            $(this).next("div").slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            $(".expand-menu .category_list").slideUp("slow");
            $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
        }
    }).first().click(); // or .trigger('click')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/EHcKs/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').eq(0).slideDown();
    $(".header").click(function() {
        $('.content').slideUp();
        $('#'+$(this).attr('target')).slideDown(500);
    });
});
```